# How to run the 'postgres' command (single-user)

Tags: postgresql

I have `postgres` installed on an ubuntu machine, and I am able to enter into the command line via something along the lines of:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
psql (10.15 (Ubuntu 10.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

And I can start/stop the server by doing something like:

```
$ sudo service postgresql
Usage: /etc/init.d/postgresql {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status} [version ..]
```

Those both seem fine. However, I would like to run postgres in single-user mode to do a couple tests. On the [`postgres`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-postgres.html) page it gives a few examples, such as:

> To start a single-user mode server, use a command like 
> `postgres --single -D /usr/local/pgsql/data other-options my_database`

However, if I use the 'postgres' command, I just get an error saying I don't have that command:

```
$ postgres

Command 'postgres' not found, did you mean:
```

What do I need to install to run the 'postgres' command in order to enter single-user mode?

Comment: i have updated my ans. can you please look into that? hope you will  find what you were asking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you have not `export` the binary path that's why it's can't find your binary of postgres.

use this command:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres --single -D /usr/local/pgsql/data other-options my_database
```

**or,**

you can **export** the path in `bash`

first open the bashrc with this command:`nano ~/.bashrc`

add this line in the end :`PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/:$PATH"`

run this command `source ~/.bashrc`

the just use `postgres --single -D /usr/local/pgsql/data other-options my_database`

you can also find where your binary is with this command : `find /usr/lib -iname 'postgres'`

Answer (score 2):

It is already installed, it is just not in your PATH, as it is not anticipated you would use it manually.

It is probably somewhere like "/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres", or you can use `locate` or `find` to find it.

Comment: thanks, could you show an example of how to use `find` or `locate` with it? I tried doing some generic `$ find` command but nearly every file had the "postgres" string in it.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has conf files spread over several places so:

/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/postgres --single -D /var/lib/postgresql/13/main -c "config_file=/etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf"